# Divergence Formula compensating for vectors that are not orthogonal of the test point.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

To my understanding, for a two-dimensional vector field

$$
\vec{F}(x,y)= \begin{bmatrix} P(x,y) \\ Q(x,y) \end{bmatrix}
$$

can model its divergence with

$$
div\vec{F}(x,y)=\frac{\partial P}{\partial x} +\frac{\partial Q}{\partial y}
$$
I get that if I isolate the x-components of vectors horizontal to whatever point I'm testing, the +/- of partial P can determine whether there is more or less "flow" into the point. But I think that this would only apply to vectors that are directly horizontal to the test point.  (same thing for y and partial Q)

But what if there was a vector whose origin didn't share an x or y coordinate with the test point? I'm pretty sure neither partials in the formula could model such a vector because the partial only models change while moving along the x or y axis at that point. I think that a vector like that could affect the divergence at a point we test, but I don't see how the formula compensates for it.

(I'm learning from [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/multivariable-derivatives/divergence-grant-videos/v/divergence-formula-part-2). At 5:30 they briefly mention this, but I don't really get it)

Comment: You’re wrong. It works for all vector fields. Just try some examples. Like $\vec F = x\vec i + y\vec j$, for starters. Khan Academy can be useful, but maybe it’s time to look at some books.

Comment: could you recommend any?

Comment: [This book](https://a.co/d/79C4vop) is a classic focusing on the particular vector integral calculus you’re interested in.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll check it out.